# How can I recover my external hard drive's free space?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, spaces

I had these partitions on an external hard drive:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Android                 63.9 GB    disk2s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS RiptideHUP              968.0 GB   disk2s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data RiptideF                967.8 GB   disk2s4
```

My aim was to delete disk2s2 and then resize disk2s3 to occupy the leftover space by deleting disk2s2. 
I deleted disk2s2 using this command:

```
diskutil  erasevolume  "Free Space"  ""  /dev/disk2s2
```

Now, to resize the volume, I used:

```
diskutil  resizevolume  /dev/disk2s3  R
```

However, I got this error:

```
Started partitioning on disk2s3 RiptideHUP Error: -69743: The new size
must be different than the existing size
```

I did a bit of research and realised the free space was created before `disk2s3 RiptideHUP` so it cannot resize itself. Is there still a way I can reclaim the Free Space?

**NOTE:** Using `diskutil list` now shows:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS RiptideHUP              968.0 GB   disk2s3
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data RiptideF                967.8 GB   disk2s4
```

Comment: How much space is RiptideHUP using? This time please do not answer 968 GB. I want to know how much space is being used by the files and folders stored on the volume with the name RiptideHUP.

Comment: You want a way to expand `disk2s3` to reclaim the free space. The only safe way to attempt this is to first backup the data on `disk2s3` to another drive. Once this is done, then there is no reason to keep `disk2s3`. You might as well delete `disk2s3` and create a new partition containing all the free space, then restore from the backup drive.

Comment: RiptideHUP has 193.02 GB occupied. It is a Time Machine Volume

Comment: Since the occupied size is larger than 63.9 GB, you will not be able to clone (copy) to a volume that could be created using the free space. Does `RiptideF` have enough unused space?

Comment: No, RiptideF has 102.1 GB occupied

Comment: The way I read your last comment is that 102.1 GB occupied would mean there is approximately `967.8 GB - 102.1 GB = 865.7 GB` of space available to temporarily store the contents of `RiptideHUP`. What is the format of `RiptideF`?

Comment: RiptideF is formatted as ExFAT as I share files between my Windows and Mac systems

Comment: I suppose a mountable image could be created to temporarily hold the time machine files. The instructions for moving a time machine backup is given [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202380). Once a backup is created, you could remove the `RiptideHUP` partition and create a new approximately `63.9 GB + 968.0 GB = 1.0319 TB partition. Copy the time machine backup to the new partition and delete the image.